# Unlocked Packages using Salesforce Platform License

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm testing the usage of a DX user using "Salesforce Platform" license.

The problem is that I cannot find the permission below on the profile. Testing with permission set show an error when I try to assign: "The user license doesn't allow the permission: Create and Update Second-Generation Packages".

- System Permissions > Create and Update Second-Generation Packages

Is this a bug?

Asking because [Salesforce DX Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm) says it should:

> You can use Salesforce DX with these Standard user licenses: Salesforce, Salesforce Platform, and Salesforce Limited Access - Free (partners only).

Comment: Have you enabled Second-Generation Packages on your DevHub?

Comment: Hi @sfdxbomb: yep I did. The problem is profile/license related I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce support mentioned that this is by design: the **Salesforce Limited Access - Free** is for Partners only and **Salesforce Platform** license cannot create **Package 2**.

Aside from that, I had to change my approach given having production access to other companies production (even though only for **Dev Hub**) was consider harmful and hard to justify by our Security team.

Thus I will continue to use **Salesforce Limited Access - Free** with our Partner **Dev Hub**.