# Salesforce DX Limited Access - access to custom objects

Tags: licenses

Has anyone been able to find the documentation for what objects are accessible for:

`Salesforce DX Limited Access` user licenses?

Specifically, what type of access to Cases and Custom Objects?

All I could find was:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_hub_license.htm

Which has limited details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no access to any standard or custom object, except for those related to Chatter and working with Scratch Orgs and Packages. It's meant to be a low-cost (free) way to add developers that don't need any standard CRM functionality. If you're hoping to model something like JIRA or a bugtracker in Salesforce, you'll need more than this license allows.

Comment: I need our developers to have `System Permissions > Create and Update Second-Generation Packages` so they can create 2GP packages, but they are using platform user licenses. Ideally I need to mash platform and salesforce DX limited licenses together to get a license that works!

Comment: @Robs I'm pretty sure Platform would work for this... but I don't have an org I can test this in.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248495/unlocked-packages-using-salesforce-platform-license answer makes me think it's not. And I cannot give the permission to one of our developers, who is using platform